# First Order Differential equation with complex coefficients: $y' + \frac1{x+i}y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for a way to solve this differential equation with complex numbers. $$(E) : y' + \dfrac{1}{x+i}y = 0$$
The professor expects a solution over the real numbers. He suggests to first split $\dfrac{1}{x+i}$ into its real and imaginary part, which I did. I fail to see what to do next. Should I only solve $(E)$ for the real part of that number?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about multiplying by $x+i$ to get
$$\left[(x+i) y \right]'=(x+i)y'+y=0? $$